# C++ Segmentation Fault while using online Compiler but the Same works in VS Code

Tags: c++11, pointers

I am new to C++ Programming. I'm getting `Segmentation Fault` error while compiling my code in online compilers but when I try compile it using `Visual Studio Code` and `g++` in offline(means in my local machine) works fine.

The `Code` I have tried is

`

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int *ptr;
    *ptr = 10;
    cout<<*ptr; //Prints 10 
    cout<<ptr; //Prints Some garbage address
}
```

But the above program not working in online compilers(used onlinegdb).
My machine configuration
`g++ 11`
`Visual Studio Code 2016`

Comment: Welcome to SO! This code doesn't make much sense. If you're trying to create an integer, remove the pointer. If you're trying to make a pointer, you'll need to allocate some memory or point it to some valid chunk of memory. Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behavior, which means it could do anything (including appear to work).

Comment: hi ggorlen, I am just playing with pointers. I am not making any meaningful code, here the unassigned poiter will contain some Garbage address right? on that we can store something likewise mentioned in a blog I read, but why there is a mismatch between online and offline compilers?

Comment: As I explained above, behavior is undefined, so literally anything can happen. See [this](https://raphlinus.github.io/programming/rust/2018/08/17/undefined-behavior.html) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It's impossible to say what happens during your `cout` lines after the null pointer derference `*ptr = 10;`. If you run this with a sanitizer like valgrind, your program will not make it past this line. I'd recommend using such a tool for all of your programs as you learn C++.

Answer (score 0):

This line `*ptr = 10;` is fundamentally wrong, as you cannot assign value by dereferencing a pointer.

The correct method of doing so, would be:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a=10;
int *ptr;
ptr=&a;
cout<<ptr<<endl;
cout<<*ptr<<endl;
```

Comment: "you cannot assign value by dereferencing a pointer" - Of course you can, as long as the point actually points somewhere.